# P4Vs pop up unacessible when opening visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, perforce, p4vs

I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version 17.8.2 and P4VS Version 2023.1.251.3916.
When starting visual studio, the pop up to open the connection to the perforce server is often unacessible and I have to manually close it before even being able to use Visual Studio.

[image]

Once I close it, I'll then be able to open a perforce connection from the "Helix connection" toolbar

[image]

Is there a way to fix the initial problem ? Thanks